# What is the difference between Angular 8 import and previous imports

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing, angular8

With Angular 8 we can import modules like so:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'customer-list',
      loadChildren: () => import('./customers/customers.module').then(m => m.CustomersModule) },
    { path: 'order-list',
      loadChildren: () => import('./orders/orders.module').then(m => m.OrdersModule) }
    ];
```

And with the previous version of Angular, we could do it like so:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'customer-list',
      loadChildren: './customers/customers.module#CustomersModule'},
    { path: 'order-list',
      loadChildren: './orders/orders.module#OrdersModule'}
    ];
```

What is the exact difference between load children with import and load children without import?

Answer (score 2):

The new standard dynamic import syntax instead of a custom string will be better able to complain in case missing or misspelled. So, this change in syntax will be taken care of you if you're using ng upgrade command to upgrade your app.
Check out this post: https://blog.mgechev.com/2019/05/11/dynamic-imports-javascript/

Comment: This is a very useful feature as I've run into issues where there was a misspelling and it took hours to figure out what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From angular `Deprecated APIs`: "When Angular first introduced lazy routes, there wasn't browser support for dynamically loading additional JavaScript. Angular created our own scheme using the syntax loadChildren: './lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' and built tooling to support it. Now that ECMAScript dynamic import is supported in many browsers, Angular is moving toward this new syntax."